# Busqueda según count de una propiedad de navegacion - C# - ASP.NET - MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Buen día.
De antemano muchas gracias por cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Actualmente estoy trabajando sobre un proyecto generado con ASP.NET y se me presento un problema al intentar generar 2 listas que voy a utilizar para mostrar un ranking en la vista.

Este es el codigo que hice, el cual evidentemente esta mal, porque puse un breakpoint para verificar y nunca toma valores el mismo, es decir que estoy plantenando mal la busqueda.

```
        var miembros = _context.Miembros
            .ToList()
            .OrderBy(miembro => miembro.Entradas.Count)
            .Where(miembro => miembro.Entradas.Count > 0)
            .Take(3);

        var topEntradas = _context.Entradas
            .ToList()
            .OrderBy(e => e.Preguntas.Count)
            .Where(e => e.Preguntas.Count > 0)
            .Take(5);
```

Para dar un poco de contexto. En el caso de los miembros, tienen una lista de entradas realizadas, así que necesito traer los 3 miembros con más entradas generadas.
Las entradas tienen una listado de preguntas, y de igual forma me gustaria tener las 5 con más preguntas generadas.

Quedo atento a cualquier dato extra que necesien y de nuevo muy agradecido con cualquier comentario que me pueda ayudar.

---

Muchas gracias por la pronta respueta y la bienvenida.
Si, se que es algo complicado poder simplificar todo en una pregunta.
Como referencia, este codigo me funciona correctamente

```
var ultimas5 = _context.Entradas
            .ToList()
            .OrderBy(ultimas5 => ultimas5.Fecha)
            .Take(5);
```

### El problema surge cuando le agrego el Count.

Toda la razón, un dato bastante importante, al intentar acceder a la lista desde la vista (lo estoy haciendo con un ciclo foreach), me arroja la excepción.

ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')

System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)

Esta salta cuando llega a la linea de donde esta el Count.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Tu pregunta es un poco complicada, dado que sin saber exactamente que datos tienen los objetos `Miembros` y `Entradas` es dificil saber porque no te está retornando los datos que esperas. Yo iría simplificando la consulta y depurando a ver que devuelve (por ejemplo,quitar el `Take` y ver que devuelve, o quitar el `Where`...) Lo único que te puedo decir es que yo personalmente haría el `Where` antes del `Orderby`, y que si quieres los que mas entradas tienen sería un `OrderByDescending`mas que `OrderBy`.

Comment: Prueba a usar `Count()` en lugar de `Count`

Comment: No, nada. 
hice algunas pruebas cambiando el orden del Where, con y sin el parentesis pero me sigue arrojando el error...
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')
System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)
Hay alguna información te pueda brinda que te haga mas sencillo el poder colaborarme?

Comment: Nunca hablaste de que te lanzara una excepción...debes añadir esa información a tu pregunta usando el botón [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Espero esta consulta te sirva:

```
var miembros = (from m in _context.Miembros
                select new
                {
                  m.Campo1,
                  m.Campo2,
                  m.CampoN,
                  Total = m.Entradas.Count()
                }).Where(m2 => m2.Total > 0).
                   OrderByDescending(m2 => m2.Total).
                   Select(m2 => new  
                   { 
                     m2.Campo1, 
                     m2.Campo2,
                     m2.CampoN
                     //No se pondria m2.Total 
                   }).Take(3).ToList();
```

Aquí usamos las **palabras claves select new** para construir un **objeto anónimo**, el cual tendrá todos los campos del **objeto miembro**, y tendrá además, un campo adicional llamado **Total** que seria el total de entradas por cada **objeto miembro**. Esto devolverá un **IEnumerable** donde cada elemento de ese **IEnumerable** será un objeto anónimo con todos los campos propios del **objeto miembro** y el nuevo **campo Total**.

A este **IEnumerable** se le aplica el **método extensor Where** donde se filtraran todos los **objetos anónimos** que cumplan con la condición **Total > 0**, posterior a este filtro se ordena descendentemente por el **campo Total** y por ultimo aplicando el **método extensor Select** se construye un nuevo **objeto anónimo**, con todos los campos que te interesen, posteriormente se tomarían los tres primeros elementos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. 
Estuve intentando y el problema se presentaba cuando intetaba hacer el Count(), indicando que no se podria hacer sobre un null. Puse ul Where antes del count validando que Entradas fuera diferente de null, y luego el conteo. Con eso funciona correctamente.